# Debugging a memory leak in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, memory-leaks

I have an application that is leaking large amounts of RAM in Firefox, only. I am certain that the leak is of DOM elements, since the size of the DOM rendered directly corresponds to the speed with which memory is consumed.

Chrome has a useful view of the heap that shows detached DOM trees:

[image]

Is there any similar capability in Firefox through which I can rule out or implicate JS code as retaining references to unmounted DOM objects?

Comment: Hi, have you ever found a solution?

Comment: @GoldenretriverYT: There was and still is nothing comparable in Firefox. IIRC, I used heap differencing; capture two heap dumps over a period of time, and then diff one against the other.

Comment: ah, I wish they would add something like this. But I will try your approach, thanks!